# Why is `Resolving` so slow in the compiling stage of SBT?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I found the Resolving step usually takes long time when I run `sbt compile`, such as this

```
[info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7 ...
```

Does anyone have ideas about what the resolving actually mean? And why is it necessary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is when ivy (which sbt uses for dependency management) looks through the dependency graph of the project to figure out all dependencies and transitive dependencies, and resolve any conflicts between those, for example, two dependencies might depend on different versions of the same library.

The result is cached, but is removed if you do a clean, so it will be recalculated on the next operation that needs to know the dependencies.

It is also possible to configure your project in ways which it so that sbt cannot cache the result but needs to redo those calculations every time you build, for example if you depend on snapshots and have configured sbt to update snapshots for every build.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to disable this output in sbt? Rationale: almost 90% of build output in runners such as Travis is "Resolving..." (and each "Resolving" is a separate line in the build log).

Comment: There is an alternative sbt starter from Paul Phillips that has a blacklist for logging output that could work: https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras

Comment: Thanks, that could be a solution - in the meantime I found a flag that does not seem to work for me (yet): https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1791

Comment: Still it looks that it takes quite a long time to look through the dependency graph of the project to figure out all dependencies and transitive dependencies. Is that step optimized in ivy or does it just scans via brute force?